# How to add X amount number from user input then add all of number in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, math, addition

```
how_many_number = int(input("How many number do you want to print? "))
```

for take_number in how_many_number:

```
take_number = int(input("Enter number: "))
sum = 0
sum = sum + take_number
```

print(sum)

Comment: Can you explain the question a bit more. Do you want to get X amount of numbers from user and then sum them?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? and may be provide some expected output

Comment: You must initialize `sum = 0` BEFORE the loop begins.  Otherwise, you're not summing.  You're just returning the last number.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. To take user input we can use a for loop and for each iteration we can add it to our sum using `+=` operator. You can read through the following code to understand it well enough.

```py
number_of_inputs = int(input("How many number to sum: ")

sum = 0  # Initialize the sum variable
for x in range(number_of_inputs):  # Repeat the number of inputs times
    sum += int(input("Enter Value: "))  # Take a input and add it to the sum

print("Sum is", sum)  # print out the sum after completing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also compress it into a List Comprehension, like this...

```py
how_many_number = int(input("How many number do you want to print? "))
print(sum([int(input("Enter number: ")) for i in range(how_many_number)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

i would use the following, note: error handle is not yet incorporated.

```
num_list = []
### create a function that adds all the numbers entered by a user
### and returns the total sum, max 3 numbers
### return functions returns the entered variables
def add_nums():
    while len(num_list) < 3:
        user_num = int(input('please enter a number to add:'))
        num_list.append(user_num)
    print('You have entered the following numbers: ',num_list)
    total_num_sum = 0
    for x in num_list:
        total_num_sum += x 
    print('total sum of numbers = ',total_num_sum)
add_nums()
```

Also, please follow the StackOverFlow post guidelines; have your post title as a problem question, it has to be interesting for other devs, and add more emphasis on why you want to add numbers entered by user vs running calc on a existing or new data-frame, need more meat.